# How to correctly plug an iPhone for charge?

Tags: charging

An Apple official article for iPhone says:

> When you use the Apple USB Power Adapter to charge iPhone, make sure the USB cable is fully inserted into the power adapter before you plug the adapter into a power outlet.

(from [iPhone User Guide at https://help.apple.com/](https://help.apple.com/iphone/11/#/iph301fc905))

This seems to hint that plugging the cable and iPhone before plugging both to the charger has some potential risk?  How so?

Comment: I do not agree with how you're interpreting the statement. To me the statement is more about not plugging the adapter into an AC outlet until after you've connected the USB cable into the adapter. It's irrelevant whether the *Lightning* end of the cable is connected to the iPhone yet or not.

Comment: I think you are right.  And I was too: that's what I meant: the article seems to hint that doing this: 1st: insert the lightning plug to the iPhone  2nd: insert the power adapter into the wall socket.  3rd: insert the USB connector into the power adapter, is not recommended (which is what many people do).  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like basic guidelines when handling electric devices: The moment with the highest risk of anything going wrong is the moment you plug something into the power outlet (or remove it from there). So it makes a lot of sense of not having your expensive device (the iPhone) already attached to the other end.

Comment: I would agree with that as a guideline - but I don't think that is what the quoted text is saying: "make sure the USB cable *is* fully inserted into the power adapter *before* you plug the adapter into a power outlet."

Answer (score 0):

This seems to just indicate that there's a shock hazard if you plug the USB plug into a charger that is already connected to the wall socket, as you may touch the bare metal on the USB-A plug.